# Easy Parity Lemma - Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to learn graph theory and came across this lemma: [Easy Parity Lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLgvr.png). I understand that if the entire graph is balanced, as defined in the image, the lemma would apply. However, I don't understand why a directed graph must be balanced. Why must it be balanced?

Comment: Nobody said that a directed graph "must" be imbalanced.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Correct, but doesn't the lemma only apply if the directed graph is balanced. Thus, it follows that the lemma implies the a directed graph must be balanced, which I don't see the be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lemma in no way whatsoever implies that a directed graph "must" be balanced.  Of course a directed graph need not be balanced:

[image: unbalanced directed graph]

"A basketball player must be tall" in no way implies that "a non-basketball player cannot be tall."

Simple logic.

Comment: Correct, but given a tree structure of a directed graph, would the lemma not fail?

Comment: What does "tree structure" have to do with anything?!?

Comment: Given [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W23a4.png) are nodes 1 and 2 not failing the easy parity lemma?

Comment: Ahh I was missing the point that the lemma does not specify that the "other" unbalanced not is not necessarily unbalanced in the opposite way.